# Keycloak as IDP with custom authenticator cant read http POST params login_hint

Tags: keycloak, idp

I have a saml Keycloak client which contains an Authentication Flow Override to a custom keycloak SPI authenticator built in java and deployed in the keycloak env. The authenticator is pretty simple, it displays a username field and takes that username, does a 3rd party check, then returns a verdict (go/nogo, yes/no, etc.)

I have a SAML SP sending a request to this keycloak client (as an IDP). The SP request has a LoginHint. When the Custom Authenticator receives this request in the authenticate method, it cannot retrieve the HTTP Post parameters because there are none.

When user enters their information into the custom authenticators form and clicks submit, and when the action method takes over, the new HTTP POST params are there.

I need to retrieve the loginHint in the authenticate method from the incoming SP SAML request.

anyone know how to do this? i cant read in the login_hint for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

login_hint and variations thereof belong to OpenID Connect (OIDC) implementations. In SAML you have to use RelayState ([recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852143/does-saml-2-0-allow-to-send-sp-data-to-idp/)) or an authentication request extension.