# SAML 2.0 RelayState params: how to add extra field to login form in WSO2 IS?

Tags: java, saml-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to add an extra combobox in my custom login page in WSO2 IS (that holds a version of product to show). The selection of the combox should be passed to service provider after success login. As it's stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852143/does-saml-2-0-allow-to-send-sp-data-to-idp) the selection can be passed as RelayState param. Still I can't find an example on how to do that with WSO2 IS. So the question is: how can I set up using a RelayState param on IS side and how to get its value on service provider side? Any example on java is strongly appretiated!

Answer (score 2):

SAML there are two flow

- IdP Initiated
- SP Initiated

**Relay State** : is the one parameter which help you in IdP Initiated flow. If There are multiple application on the service provider side and after SAML assertion if you need to identify in which application user has to land then you can use relay state. Either you can directly configure application URL in relay state parameter or you can configure some values which help you to identify application.

> To make this work, IdP initiated SSO should be enabled in your IdP.

Inside a WSO2 IdP there is SSO settings may be you can get RelayState configuration there. I did configured RelayState for other IdP,  which can be easily configured.

Following code you can use to get RelayState on SP side

```
public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential credential)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    
    // The method is supposed to identify local account of user referenced by
    // data in the SAML assertion and return UserDetails object describing the user.
    
    String userID = credential.getNameID().getValue();
    String relayState = credential.getRelayState();
    
    LOG.info(userID + " is logged in");
    

    return new User(userID, "<abc123>", true, true, true, true, authorities);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But how can I tell WSO2 IS to accept field of form on login page to relay state parameter or how can I pass field value to SP in any othe way?

Comment: Not sure but you can use saml assertion xml for the same. if you see, you want to drive sp landing page from version selected on UI.  to achieve same by RelayState is there. As I see in my IdP that I can create multiple application on there for Multiple versions.  So that user choose required applciaton and  based on relayState configuration at IdP for that application SP redirect works.  I am not sure about the WSO2 how you can achieve there.